# Crash when assigning rootViewController in the AppDelegate programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, nscoder

I am not using a storyboard so, I got a problem in the `AppDelegate`. Look's like very easy but I cannot solve the problem.

My `Appdelegate.swift` file code is the following.

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
window?.rootViewController = LineChartViewController(coder: NSCoder.init())
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

My Custom `LineChartViewController.swift` file code is below.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    }
```

After run this code, i got a Error message which is "`decodeObjectForKey: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class NSCoder: Create a concrete instance!'`"

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You don't want to be using `NSCoding` here.

`NSCoding` is used for to archive and unarchive objects to and from an `NSData` format, you just want to create a new `LineChartViewController` instance.

Therefore you want to do the following, when you set the `rootViewController`:

```
window?.rootViewController = LineChartViewController()
```

And to do setup, you should override `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
}
```

Comment: Thank you! originalsuer2! i am very curious about nscoding. can you explain more about archive unarchive objects to an from an nsdata?

Comment: Sure, it's mainly used to either write and read objects to and from disk, or to convert objects into a format where they can be sent and received (such as over a network). See the [conceptual docs on archiving for more](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/archives.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000946-BAJDBJAI) and [NSHipster's nice tutorial on using it](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/).